# How do I convert Swift project into a static library

Tags: ios, swift, static-libraries, static-linking

I know how to convert a Objective c project into static libary.

Basically it can be converted to a .a static library

Here is a [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

But swift project can't be converted to static library it can be converted to Dynamic framework.

AFAIK its not possible.

I couldn't find a way to do that

Anybody have any approach on how to do that?

Comment: "Basically it can be converted to a .a static library" "But swift project can't be converted to static library"  Please revise your confusing statements.

Comment: Not particularly.  He said an Objective-C project can be made into a static library.  But a swift project can only be made into a dynamic library.

Comment: @DavidBerry - Swift project can be turned into cocoa touch framework.I never knew it can be turned it  into dynamic library.Can it be ?

Comment: Functionally, a framework is a dynamic library.

Comment: I read somewhere dynamic library is forbidden in iOS its allowed in OSX only

Comment: with swift we can't create static library the only would be creating a framework.so framework is basically collection of static and dynamic libraries but dynamic library we shouldn't use as dynamic linking is opposed to apple rules.so swift project is turned into framework it has to contain static library its quite contradicting... Can you go in detail about this ?